# Xcode 8 / Swift 3 / ios 10 navigation bar changes?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am returning to "old" xcode 7 / swift 2 project.

Something odd has happened across all my navigations bars.

I have code like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var outletCatalogNav: UINavigationItem!

//...

outletCatalogNav.title = "my title";

//...

outletCatalogNav.leftbarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ownCatalogBackButton));

//...    

if (outletCatalogNav.leftbarButtonItem != nil) {
  outletCatalogNav.leftbarButtonItem.leftBarButtonItem!.title = " back"
}
```

This then ends in code like this for switching views:

```
TmpOldViewController.present(TmpNewViewController!, animated: TmpAnimate, completion: nil):
```

*Info: For historic reasons I handle view controller changes myself as the iOS app code was converted from an entirely different development platform, language and environment.*

Anyhow, in the past the button would simply be placed to the left of the caption. Now in ios10 simulator at least it is rendered kinda below (but still to the left) meaning the original height I have used for the navigation bar no longer suffices (since it is being covered by other controls) - in the screenshot below you can see this with the hint of the blue text bottom left.

[image]

Constraints are:

```
Navigation Bar.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom
TableViewCatalog.top = Navigation Bar.bottom
Navigation Bar.leading = leadingMargin - 20
trailingMargin = Navigation Bar.trailing - 20
```

What changed? I was unable o find any reference to changes happening in navigation bar. For reference, since changing to swift 3 I am now only targeting ios8+ so I do not need ios7 compatible solution.

Comment: Are you using an independent navigation bar, then (meaning, the bar only, without a navigation controller)?

Comment: @leanne Yes - I have added more code and explanation just in case it is relevant.

Comment: Another couple of questions: 1) What other constraints do you have for the navigation bar? 2) Does it do the same thing when run on an actual device?

Comment: @leanne Navigation Bar.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom and TableViewCatalog.top = Navigation Bar.bottom (will test on an iphone 6 later today, had to ditch my test iphone 4 after ios8+ requirement so using simulator at present)

Comment: Try to replace the `.title = "back"` by creating a whole new `UIBarButtonItem`. I think there is some change in the way the frame for the bar button item is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some insane trial and error in **viewDidLoad()** I found why this error occurs:

If I create the button with an empty title I get the problem, i.e. like this:

```
outletCatalogNav.leftbarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ownCatalogBackButton));
```

Create with a non-empty title and it works:

```
outletCatalogNav.leftbarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ownCatalogBackButton));
```

In both cases the title is actually also set later - but what matters is having a non-empty title when creating the button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what changed in iOS 10 regarding independent nav bar, so I can't answer your question specifically. However, I can tell you two possible methods to fix it:

**1) Set the proper constraints and values for an independent navigation bar:**
Ensure the constraints are set as follows:
- Navigation Bar.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom
- Navigation Bar.Leading = Superview.Leading
- Navigation Bar.Trailing = Superview.Trailing

Then, in the Identity Inspector for the bar, add a user defined attribute with these values:
- Key Path: barPosition
- Type: Number
- Value: 3

This installs the independent nav bar in such a way that it will act as though it's attached to a nav controller.

***Note***: the bar will appear in the storyboard as though it's not the right height. That's okay! It'll adjust appropriately when you actually run the app.

**Update: the same solution, but without using the "user defined attribute":**
- Ensure the constraints are set as described above.
- Connect the storyboard's navigation bar to its view controller as an @IBOutlet.
- In the view controller's class, add a UINavigationBarDelegate protocol to the class declaration.
- In the view controller's viewDidLoad method, set the navigation bar's delegate to self.
- In the view controller, add the bar positioning delegate's positionForBar method. Return the UIBarPosition representing TopAttached. (Note: UINavigationBarDelegate inherits this method from UIBarPositioningDelegate.)

For further details, see [Easily use a Navigation Bar without a corresponding Navigation Controller](http://user3526.blogspot.com/2016/03/easily-use-navigation-bar-without.html) for demo GIFs.

For further details on the "user defined attribute" method, see [Even more easily use a Navigation Bar without a corresponding Navigation Controller!](http://user3526.blogspot.com/2016/03/even-more-easily-use-navigation-bar.html)

**2) Embed the view into a navigation controller:**
- In the storyboard, delete the "independent" navigation bar.
- Make sure the view with the navigation bar is selected.
- From the menu, select Editor/Embed In/Navigation Controller.

***Note***: You don't need to code anything or make a subclass for the nav controller. It'll just automagically handle your navigation bar appropriately.

---

On a side note: I have an app, created in iOS 7, that also had an independent nav bar. In Xcode 8/iOS 10, it had your same issue.

I used the first method above, which fixed the nav bar issues. However, then I had a flicker on launch (something to do with the animation of the bar in iOS 10, perhaps).

I was using a launch image. It occurred to me that the image might be off versus the nav bar animation. So, I switched to method 2, embedding my view into a nav controller. Then, I removed the launch image I had been using, and added a new launch screen - built with the view embedded in a nav controller. Together, that took care of the flicker.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not setting: TableViewCatalog.top = Navigation Bar.bottom? Can I keep that?

Comment: Using solution #1: What you do by setting barPosition - can that be done runtime somehow?

Comment: Your solution #2 - would it not essentially mean I would have to remove or at least rewrite all my own logic for I use across entire app for controlling which view to present? (It is a fairly simple stackbased logic, but still - theoreticly I might some day prefer to "back" multiple levels)

Comment: I have added a screenshot from the simulator - is that the same as you saw?

Comment: Yes, you can keep your `TableViewCatalog.top = Navigation Bar.bottom`. And, yes, there's a way to do solution #1 at runtime. See this blog post: [Easily use a Navigation Bar without a corresponding Navigation Controller](http://user3526.blogspot.com/2016/03/easily-use-navigation-bar-without.html)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include basic instructions and links to both versions of solution #1.

Comment: I would love to give bounty for it (upvoted answer and comments) - but the problem still stands as shown in the screenshot. I will try experiment some more. I think leftBarButtonItem simply behaves differently now somehow. I have also experimented setting leftBarButtonItem title to a single character to see if it is some kind of wrapping issue... But that does not solve the issue either - still placed below

Comment: I will award bounty - but not accept the answer until I can confirm it is working.

Comment: Note: you must NOT have a specific height set for the nav bar. If you are specifically setting a height somewhere, the bar can't auto adjust itself correctly.

Comment: In interface builder height is 44 (greyed so I can not change it) - I do not set height runtime. But the frustrating thing is that visually there appears to be a ton of space on both sides of the title (see screenshot - did your problem look the same as that? i.e. the blue text at bottomleft should have been on the same horizontal line as the title)

Comment: If it has any relevance... rightBarButtonItem is placed correcly to the right at same vertical point. but leftBarButtonItem is placed below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138873/discussion-between-leanne-and-tom).

Comment: I actually found a solution I have verified. It is possible yours also helped - but doing trial and error (the right button led me to some more experiments) I found another cause for the error and a solution